# ArgumentError in Admin::Users#new Rails 4 active admin gem with devise ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am converting rails 3 application to rails 4 with ruby 2.0 .

```
devise (~> 3.2)
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

My user.rb file in admin look like following

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
before_filter { @skip_sidebar = true }
filter :email
filter :role, as: :check_boxes, collection: User::ROLES
filter :created_at

index do
column :email
column :role
column :created_at
column :current_sign_in_at
column :current_sign_in_ip, sortable: false
default_actions
end

show :title => :email do |ad|
attributes_table do
  row :email
  row :role
  row :created_at
  row :sign_in_count
  row :current_sign_in_at
  row :current_sign_in_ip
  row :last_sign_in_at
  row :last_sign_in_ip
end
active_admin_comments
end

form partial: 'form'

member_action :create, :method => :post do
@user = User.new(params[:user], as: :admin)
if @user.save

  redirect_to [:admin, @user]
else
  render action: "new"
end
end

member_action :update, :method => :put do
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user], as: :admin)
  redirect_to [:admin, @user]
else
  render action: "edit"
 end
 end

end
```

I had also created the new user partial to customize the view and it is as follow

```
- semantic_form_for [:admin, @user] do |f|
  - f.inputs do
    = f.input :email
    = f.input :role, collection: User::ROLES, include_blank: false
  - f.actions do
    = f.action :commit
    = f.action :cancel
```

but I got the following error

```
ArgumentError in Admin::Users#new

Showing /dffsdfs/app/views/admin/users/_form.html.haml where line #1 raised:

wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

Extracted source (around line #1):

- semantic_form_for [:admin, @user] do |f|
  - f.inputs do
    = f.input :email
    = f.input :role, collection: User::ROLES, include_blank: false
```

Answer (score 0):

when you build the form `semantic_form_for` needs to have the attributes as the model in this case  admin is not a model

you need use this:

```
- semantic_form_for @user do |f|
  - f.inputs do
    = f.input :email
    = f.input :role, collection: User::ROLES, include_blank: false
```

Comment: Actually I need to just remove the meta_search gem from gem file and it start working but thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: bad way `meta_search` need for good search and filter for `active_admin`

Comment: @Monk_Code meta_search has been replaced by Ransack on the latest Active Admin code on Github, which is what OP is using.

Answer (score 0):

I need to remove the mete_search gem from my gem file and then it works.